# Can a Doppelganger's clone use an encounter ability?

Tags: gamma-world, gamma-world-7e

So, in my group we have a Doppelganger Yeti. Her yeti ability is an encounter ability (Big Claws) that allows her to make an attack for a minor action. Does Big Claws go on Cooldown (not being able to use it) if her clone use the ability?

Double Trouble only says that the clone cannot use doppelganger abilities, alpha mutations or Omega Tech.

Let's imagine this situation :

- First turn

  - Doppelganger → Uses Double Trouble
  - Clone → Uses Big Claws
- Next Turn

  - Doppelganger → Uses Double Trouble

Can the clone use Big Claws again?

I'm using Gamma World 7th editon for reference.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

As per RAW, it "can take all the actions that you can take, except that it can't use doppelganger powers, Alpha Mutations, or Omega Tech." As long as the action is not one of the three excluded types, it is allowed.